# What does //![1] mean in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I was going through a code.

```
void GZMainWindow::connectMarkers_cx()
{
     //![1]
    // Connect all markers to handler
       const auto markers = cx_chart->legend()->markers();
        for (QLegendMarker *marker : markers) 
     {
        
        QObject::disconnect(marker, &QLegendMarker::clicked,
                            this, &GZMainWindow::handleMarkerClicked);
        QObject::connect(marker, &QLegendMarker::clicked, this, &GZMainWindow::handleMarkerClicked);
    }
     //![1]
}
```

What does //![1] mean? Is it used for segmentation of code or function ?

Comment: It is for the [`QDoc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-guide-writing.html)

Comment: This type of comments can be used by QDoc or Doxygen to generate code documentation as mentioned by @thibsc above.